# How do I tell Aptana Studio to use Python virtualenv?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, ubuntu

I did some searches on this topic and the solutions didn't work for me.  I am running both a Linux (Ubuntu) environment and Windows.  My system is Windows 8.1 but I have virtualbox with Ubuntu on that.
Starting with Windows...  I created a venv directory off the root of the e drive.  Created a project folder and then ran the activate command, which is in the venv>Scripts directory.  So, after activating that (note, I had installed virtualenv already)... so after activating that I then changed into the folder with my module and it ran fine, with the shebang, I didn't even have to type python in front of my filename.  However, in Aptana Studio, it cannot find the module I installed with pip.  So, it doesn't work.  In an earlier post it was recommended that one choose a different interpreter and browse to the env and select that.

So, how does one get this installed and working with an IDE like Eclipse and Aptana Studio?

I am having problems on Ubuntu.  The instructions I found had me using package installer to install virtualenv, pip and a few other tools that package these.  The problem is that on Ubuntu the default version of python is 2.7.x.  I need 3.3 or 3.x.  So, can someone point me in the direction of how to setup virtual environments  for the 2.7.x branch of python and the 3.x branch.

Also, how does one tell the IDE (Eclipse or Aptana Studio) to use the virtualenv?
Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: As an additional note, should I have a virtualenv for 2.7.x and 3.x in one location each and reference the one that I need, when needed.  That may not work, as I tried once to activate a directory and then move to the directory above it, and that failed.  Maybe if I could have a command to active a python 2.7.x environment from anywhere and the same for python 3.x then that would be most ideal.  I may need python 2.7.x for some projects, though I'd most often choose python 3.

Comment: does it help if you change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python` ?when activating a v-env, it put the chosen python interpreter at the top of the search-path. If you start eclipse/aptana from that shell they will inherete that environment.

Comment: also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301534/aptana-python-stdlib-issue-with-virtualenv?rq=1

Comment: I thought that virtualenv could be used to handle using both python3 and python2.  On Ubuntu when installing prerequisites for virtualenv, it downloaded python27 versions of everything.  How do I say, "give me a virtual env and use python 2.7" or "give me a virtual env and use python3.x?"  Maybe a silly question but are there different versions of virtualenv and pip that work with diff versions of python?  Like if using python 2.7, use this version of pip, or if python 3, use this other version of pip?

Answer (score 5):

**Configure Aptana Studio's python interpreter( you can configure more than one)**

In aptana, **Window -> Preferences -> Interpreter Python** and create a **New** interpreter. Select the python executable from the virtual environment (in windows it is `python.exe` which resides in Scripts subfoler of the virtualenv,where as in ubuntu python is under `bin` subfolder) . Now Aptana will show a list of directories to add also remember to check **C:\Python27\Lib** or Ubuntu conterpart.

Now on creating use this interpreter.

Or if to use with existing project

Step 1.Take project properties(File -> Properties OR By right clicking on Project).

Step 2.From **PyDev Interpreter/Grammer** select the interpreter you configured above.

**Edit :**

In this way you can even configure both python 3 and python 2 for Aptana. You have to configure an interpreter for each python 3 and python 2. Then follow steps above to select the interpreter.

Comment: I am successful in doing this with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04/14.04