# howto: Setup Aptana Studio to use Python virtualenv?

Tags: python, macos, aptana3

I'm attempting to run aptana studio in a virtualenv setup on the mac.  It keeps using the environment outside of the virtualenv.

**Has anyone successfully gotten virtualenv working with aptana studio?**

i've tried to apply this [How do I tell Aptana Studio to use Python virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504617/how-do-i-tell-aptana-studio-to-use-python-virtualenv) to the mac version but no luck.

What I have done so far:

In the terminal

- cd ~/Desktop
- virtualenv payload
- cd payload
- source bin/activate

In Aptana

- Aptana > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters
- click New on Python Interpreters
- selected ~/Desktop/payload/bin/python2.7/
- Default Setup
  [image: Default Setup]
- My Setup for the virtualenv
  [image: My Setup]
- I noticed the system libs don't seem to be the same not sure if that's an issue
- next right-clicked on the project itself selected properties
- selected the project and clicked edit
  [image: Edit Properties]
- Changed the Interpreter tab from default to pythonFinal but noticed each time I go back to the settings it goes back to default
- Here's my settings for the individual project properties.

[image: Properties-Main]
[image: Properties-Interpreter]

- Pressed the see results from the command-line for given parameters got

> /Users/-USERNAME-OMITTED-/Desktop/payload/bin/python -u
>
> /Users/-USERNAME-OMITTED-/Desktop/payload/source/test.py
>
> The PYTHONPATH that will be used is:
>
> /Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages`

- Next I installed the python-crontab into the virtualenv
- by using pip install python-crontab

here's the working code that works outside of the virtualenv if I install python-crontab

```
def main(): 
    print "Run Complete. "

    from crontab import CronTab

    cron = CronTab(user=True)

    job = cron.new(command='python /opt/my_script.py')
    job.setall(2, 10, '2-4', '*/2', 3) 
    cron.write()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

- It doesn't seem to be using the virtualenv python-crontab because it creates an error.

Question:
- what in the aptana studio have I not configured correctly?

Comment: You say that you created the virtualenv on your Desktop, but the first pictures show pythonFinal to be in Downloads; so you're never using the python executable from your virtualenv.

Comment: thanks i've updated the references and added a bit more details