# How do you setup virtualenv on linux for both python 2.7 and python 3.2?

Tags: python, linux, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I did reference this other SO question to see if it answered my question, and it really didn't.  I am referring to this question.  [Aptana Python stdlib issue with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301534/aptana-python-stdlib-issue-with-virtualenv?rq=1) .  I have some projects that use python 3.x and some that might prefer python 2.7.x.  This might be another topic but while I'm here, I was wondering if django and flask require python 2.7.x.  If not, then I don't really have any projects requiring python 2.7.x, only python 3.x.y.  Anyway, on Ubuntu, when trying to install pip and virtualenv it was using python 2.7.x and I was trying to create a virtual environment which would use python 3.x.y.  Strangely, this was easier to accomplish on Windows - so many things are so much harder on Windows than Linux.

The problem that exists on both platforms is that I cannot figure out how to create virtual environments based on the python 2.7 and the python 3.x versions separately.  I can setup my path variable on Windows so that python3.3.3 is the first version of python it finds and so that is essentially the default.  I would have to go into my path environment variable and put python27 in the path before python33, then when I installed virtualenv I would have a python 2.7 environment.  That doesn't seem like the best way to do things, nor would it persist.  Similarly on Ubuntu, I'd have to modify the path variable and then source the file to switch between different python installs - 2.7 or 3.x.

Can someone tell me a better way to do this?  Perhaps a reference to instructions for how to create two different virtual environments for the different python versions?
Also, confusing about the first reference link above, is how does eclipse/aptana know to activate that virtual env?
Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: Have you tried with the -p flag? `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/pythonXXX` being X the interpreter you want to create

Comment: i am not sure how you can accomplish this but  there is a way to import function from lets say python2.7 when working with  python 3. Like in a regular `import` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First you install [python-virtualenv](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-virtualenv). Then create a virtualenv using the [virtualenv command](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#usage). Read the docs for more info .